# How to prevent user from modifying certain fields in OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

On edit an existing entity all fields (except the key) are modifiables. Is there a way to indicate that some field is not modifiable?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare any property of the view read only using the [@ReadOnly](https://www.openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/apidocs/org/openxava/annotations/ReadOnly.html) annotation:

```
@ReadOnly
private String name;
```

Moreover, you can define the property not modifiable only for certain view:

```
@ReadOnly(forViews="SomeMembersReadOnly")
private String name;
```

@ReadOnly can also be applied to references:

```
@ReadOnly @ManyToOne
private Customer customer;
```

And collections:

```
@ReadOnly @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private Collection<Invoice> invoices;
```